# Is there a way to extract types of places, or types of sites, from a field in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Words': 'MONTGOMERY'}, 
       {'Words': 'HOSPITAL'},
       {'Words': 'CAMPUS'},
       {'Words': 'STADIUM'},
       {'Words': 'TOWER'},
       {'Words': 'CASINO'},
       {'Words': 'COUNTY'},
       {'Words': 'CENTER'},
       {'Words': 'ARENA'},
       {'Words': 'CRANBERRY'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I am trying to extract types of places from this dataframe. I tested some TF-IDF code. That didn't give me anything useful. I tried to extract nouns using TextBlob, and that returned everything!

```
from textblob import TextBlob
txt = df.to_string()
blob = TextBlob(txt)
print(blob.noun_phrases)
```

I would like to end up with a list that looks like this: 'HOSPITAL', 'CAMPUS', 'STADIUM', 'TOWER',  'CASINO', 'CENTER', 'ARENA'. Maybe 'TOWER' and 'CENTER' can be a little ambiguous, but I know 'HOSPITAL', 'STADIUM', and 'ARENA' are all places. Is there a way to do that? Again, I'm trying to get types of places, or types of sites.

Comment: how do you define a `place`? how do you define a `site`?

Comment: Right now, I don't know. It seems like 'CASINO' is a place and it seems like 'CRANBERRY' is not a place.  That's what I'm trying to figure out. I read about Geoparsing today. I've never done that before. Maybe this is the way to go. Not totally sure.